# Apply CSS when all dropdown is changed Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have to apply some css when all dropdown is changed. Please help me with this.

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="company1" class="dropdown">
  <option value="1">Group 1</option>
  <option value="2">Group 2</option>
</select>
<select name="company2" class="dropdown">
  <option value="1">Group 1</option>
  <option value="2">Group 2</option>
</select>
<select name="company3" class="dropdown">
  <option value="1">Group 1</option>
  <option value="2">Group 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/addClass or https://api.jquery.com/css

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve/what isn't working for you.

Comment: I want to apply css when all dropdown is selected. Alert is just for test.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cnt1=0,cnt2=0,cnt3=0;
$(".one").change(function(){
    cnt1=1;
    if((cnt1==1) && (cnt2==1) && (cnt3==1)){
        alert('test');
    }
});
$(".two").change(function(){
    cnt2=1;
    if((cnt1==1) && (cnt2==1) && (cnt3==1)){
        alert('test');
    }
});
$(".three").change(function(){
    cnt3=1;
    if((cnt1==1) && (cnt2==1) && (cnt3==1)){
        alert('test');
    }
});
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select name="company1" class="dropdown one">
        <option value="1">Group 1</option>
        <option value="2">Group 2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="company2" class="dropdown two">
        <option value="1">Group 1</option>
        <option value="2">Group 2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="company3" class="dropdown three">
        <option value="1">Group 1</option>
        <option value="2">Group 2</option>
    </select>
```